# DrawableTop not showing after migrating to androidx

Tags: android

I have a button with text and icon drawable positioned at the top but after migrating to androidx the icon doesn't show on the text does.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/activity_advanced_seats_btn_reserved_key"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_seat_reserved_key"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:text="Reserved"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  android:textAllCaps="false"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="12sp"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:enabled="false" />
```

Comment: Maybe try drawableTopCompat

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that it was indeed working but I could not see the image, had to remove the default tint on the button before the icon finally showed:

```
app:iconTint="@null"
```